# Error when using Ninject( Version Ninject v3.0.0) IOC for Sitecore 7.5 solr

Tags: solr, sitecore, ninject, sitecore7.5

I got error "Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'Sitecore.ContentSearch.ProviderIndexConfiguration'."  after adding in Global.ascx

```html
 <%@Application Language='C#' ' Inherits="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.NinjectIntegration.NinjectApplication" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried setting up SOLR with Ninject but I've got this working with CastleWindsor in the global.asax as follows:

```csharp
<%@Application Language='C#' Inherits="Sitecore.Web.Application" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Castle.Windsor" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.CastleWindsorIntegration" %>

<script runat="server">

public Castle.Windsor.IWindsorContainer Container { get; set; }

public void Application_Start() {
 try
 {
   // start up solr
   this.Container = new Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer();
   var startup = new Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.CastleWindsorIntegration.WindsorSolrStartUp(this.Container);
   startup.Initialize();
 }
 catch(Exception e){

    Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Error("Cannot connect to Solr", e, this);      }
}
</script>
```

It should be a case of swapping out the CastleWindsor for Ninject.

Comment: I have to use Ninject because I have already installed few module. Those uses a advance versions of Castle and Microsoft unity. Solr uses Castle Version 3.1.0.0.